# Click and drag to move script drags to the left

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to apply this script to a 360 video as shown in this video;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0HGtmv4nII

However I have a problem where just holding down left click will move the camera left of the Y axis.

Does anybody know why this would happen exactly? Here's the script shown in the video if it helps

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using System;



public class VRCamera : MonoBehaviour

{ // flag to keep track whether we are dragging or not

public bool isDragging = false;



// starting point of a camera movement

float startMouseX;

float startMouseY;



// Camera component

public Camera cam;

// Start is called before the first frame update

void Start()

{

// Get our camera component

cam = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();

}



// Update is called once per frame

void Update()

{



// if we press the left button and we haven't started dragging

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isDragging)

{

// set the flag to true

isDragging = true;



// save the mouse starting position

startMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;

startMouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;

}

// if we are not pressing the left btn, and we were dragging

else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && isDragging)

{

// set the flag to false

isDragging = false;

}

}



void LateUpdate()

{

// Check if we are dragging

if (isDragging)

{

//Calculate current mouse position

float endMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;

float endMouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;



//Difference (in screen coordinates)

float diffX = endMouseX - startMouseX;

float diffY = endMouseY - startMouseY;



//New center of the screen

float newCenterX = Screen.width / 2 + diffX;

float newCenterY = Screen.height / 2 + diffY;



//Get the world coordinate , this is where we want to look at

Vector3 LookHerePoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(newCenterX, newCenterY, cam.nearClipPlane));



//Make our camera look at the "LookHerePoint"

transform.LookAt(LookHerePoint);



//starting position for the next call

startMouseX = endMouseX;

startMouseY = endMouseY;

}

}

}
```

Comment: There isn't anything that actually changes the position of the camera, you might be feeling the "LookAt" as movement. Can you confirm if it changes position in editor?

Comment: It changes position in the editor as shown in this video I uploaded; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0StAWWj1LM I'm completely unsure what's causing this now as it appears to now change on the X axis and not the Y axis (at least not much more than 0.001)